# Magento 1.9.2.2 Patches onward - What is the list?

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

I have an installation of Magento 1.9.2.2 and I am lost of how to know what security patches I need to install. I have not installed any since I first installed this installation. I checked the directory app/etc and no file for installed patches is there.

Answer (score 2):

Magento depends on a manual system to do this stuff. To find out what patches apply to Magento 1.9.2.2, you need to go to the [Magento Download page](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download), click the Release Archive tab and scroll down till you get to the Ver 1.9.x bar.

Each version has a listing in ascending order of the patches included as follows:

```
ver 1.9.2.4  - Added Feb 23, 2016  
Includes patches: SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-5994, SUPEE-6237, SUPEE-6285,
SUPEE-6482, SUPEE-6788, SUPEE-7616, SUPEE-7405, SUPEE-7405 v1.1

ver 1.9.2.3  - Added Jan 20, 2016  
Includes patches: SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-5994, SUPEE-6237, SUPEE-6285,
SUPEE-6482, SUPEE-6788, SUPEE-7616, SUPEE-7405

ver 1.9.2.2  - Added Oct 27, 2015  
Includes patches: SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-5994, SUPEE-6237, SUPEE-6285,
SUPEE-6482, SUPEE-6788

ver 1.9.2.1  - Added Aug 4, 2015  
Includes patches: SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-5994, SUPEE-6237, SUPEE-6285,
SUPEE-6482

ver 1.9.2.0  - Added Jul 7, 2015  
Includes patches: SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-5994, SUPEE-6285

ver 1.9.1.1  - Added May 1, 2015  
Includes patch for the SUPEE-5344 issue
```

Everything before this was the by gosh and by golly mode where you have to look up all the applicable items in the version dropdown and pray you got them all.

Scroll back up the page to each item you will need:

```
SUPEE-7616
SUPEE-7405
SUPEE-7405 v1.1
```

Find the one appropriate to your version (1.9.2.2) and download them.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for available patches using the command line as explained at https://gist.github.com/piotrekkaminski/9bc45ec84028611d621e

> 1. First you need to generate download token. Login to your account on magento.com and generate it in Account Settings->Downloads Access Token
> 2. You will need your MAGEID as well. It is shown at the top-left in your account page.
> 3. curl -k https://MAGEID:TOKEN@www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/info/help
> 4. Profit!

To check which patches are required for Magento 1.9.2.2, run

```
curl -k https://$MAGEID:$MAGETOKEN@www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/info/filter/version/1.9.2.2
```

with $MAGEID and $MAGETOKEN being your id and token from above.
To download a file from the list, run

```
curl -O https://$MAGEID:$MAGETOKEN@www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/file/$FILENAME
```

with $FILENAME being the patch file name.